# $digest iterations reached. Simple example with ng-event

Tags: angularjs

This example keeps a count of each user clicks. The check box shows an age/name. When the check box is clicked I want the counter to be updated. When the age or name is clicked, I also want the counter updated.

The checkbox `ng-click` function is where the `$digest` iteration is having problems. If I removed the `$scope.counter ++` from this function it works fine. `line 32 of app.js`

I think this is happening because the $scope.counter is causing a new digest cycle which causes the $scope.clicked function to be called, and so on. However, I can't think of how I should be doing this to increase it just once.

You can find the example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sk6lwj?p=info

I'll post code here as well.

```
  <p>Click Count: {{clickCount}}.</p>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in testData">
          <td>
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.check" ng-checked="clicked(row)" />
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span ng-show="row.show" class="reason-show-hide" ng-click="nameClicked(row.name)">{{row.name}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span ng-show="row.show" class="reason-show-hide" ng-click="ageClicked(row.age)">{{row.age}}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS

```
var testData = [{
  name: 'Moe',
  age: 22,
  show: false
}, {
  name: 'Curly',
  age: 23,
  show: false
}, {
  name: 'Shemp',
  age: 20,
  show: false
}];
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);
app.value('testData', testData);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, testData) {

  var initialLoad = true;
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.clickCount = 0;
  $scope.testData = testData;
  $scope.clicked = function(row) {

    if (row.check === true)
      row.show = true;
    else
      row.show = false;


// this line causes the $digest loop
    $scope.clickCount++;
    console.log("Click Count updated by:" + row.name + " checkbox");

  };

  initialLoad = false;

  $scope.nameClicked = function(msg) {
    $scope.clickCount++;
    console.log("Click count updated by:" + msg + " name clicked");
  };
  $scope.ageClicked = function(msg) {

    $scope.clickCount++;
    console.log("Click count updated by:" + msg + " aged clicked");
  };

  $scope.shouldShow = function(row) {
    return row.show;
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

The problem is in line 33, you have :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.check" ng-checked="clicked(row)" />
```

but I think it should be

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.check" ng-click="clicked(row)" />
```

`ng-checked` is Angular directive for `checked` attribute not a event handler that for setting/unsetting checkbox, so that it was called and evaluated by the Angular in a loop.

With only this one change it works :

http://plnkr.co/edit/WXGjCrnmZYpJE4jZ9ljn?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much. This started as an exercise to try the animation, but turned to why does it do this. Your explanation makes sense.